# How to configure two hibernate transactionManager for two different sessions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, transactional

I have a project which deals with two different database instances.
Each access to a database is transactional, but the transaction on database1 do not need to be linked to transaction on database2.

I am using Hibernate and spring-tx 4.0.3 Release, spring Ioc4 and hibernate4.

I use `@Transactional` annotation in my DAO services.

So I configure two datasource beans, two sessionFactory beans and two HibernateTransactionManager beans.

But doing so, I get an `UniqueBeanException`  as the `TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager` tries to find only one instance of class implementing `PlatformTransactionManager` interface.

I have seen that I can make my java configuration class implements `TransactionManagementConfigurer`, so that I can specifically tell which transaction-manager bean to use, and I was hoping to implement a `ProxyTransactionManager` who could delegate to each appropriate transaction-manager depending on which database the current call need to be made.

The problem is implementing such `ProxyPlatformTransactionManager` methods, how can I know which database is being accessed, or which `SessionFactory` is being accessed? Otherwise I an not know which `PlatformTransactionManager` to use.

Has anyone faced that type of issue yet?

Thanks,

Mel

Comment: Simply specify in the [`@Transactional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#value--) annotation which tx manager it applies to and spring will do it for you. No need for additional classes.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, I did think about that :) But unfortunately, some of my Hibernate objects are defined in some jar libraries. So If I use this approach, I need to hack all those classes in order to input the appropriate tx manager. Unless maybe there is a way to set the default tx manager to one of the bean ?

Answer (score 1):

In your application context, you need to define 2 transactionalManagers as below

```
<bean id="txMngr1" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory1">
    <qualifier value="txMngr1"/>
</bean>
<bean id="txMngr2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory2">
    <qualifier value="txMngr2"/>
</bean>
```

And then use the Transactional Qualifier with your DAOs/Services.

```
@Transactional("txMngr2")
```

FYI: You can access multiple sessionFactories from your code using qualifiers as well

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="sessionFactory2")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```